# QtWebkit: Support for javascript page opens?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I'm trying to get QtWebkit to allow page opens via Javascript without success.

I don't use QWebView, only QWebPage (running headless). I derived from QWebPage and overrode createWindow (currently my override just logs a message and calls the base createWindow). I also set JavascriptCanOpenWindows to true.

My function *is* called but the base createWindow never seems to return anything but NULL and never a QWebPage. Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Can you post a minimal code sample?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the createWindow() from the QWebPage implementation returns NULL.

In my program I return the instance of my class derived from QWebPage from the createWindow(). To customize the processing of the new page I re-implement the acceptNavigationRequest() method.

It was very helpful for me to read the [browser application example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/examples-webkit.html) from the Qt examples which shows how it handles creation of a new window.